# How connect GSM nodes to VPN/proxy?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, gsm

If the GSM node has a private address which is managed by the internal network of the provider, how can I connect it to a VPN/proxy and expect it to work? As far as I know it wouldn't be a public address, and therefore not accessible from the outside?

It would only make sense if the VPN/proxy service is also offered by the same provider, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: Wow! Three people have so far voted "unclear what you're asking"! But I think I can understand the question. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** If the provider says you can access the public network, you can!

To enable you to access the public network from within a private network, the provider can maintain a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) device. With this device in place, communication between the public and private network is possible as along as the initiator of the communication is a client in the private network. (That's not strictly true, but for the sake of this answer, it is true enough.)

Connections to a VPN server or a proxy server are no different than ordinary connections. (Again, that's not strictly true, but for the sake of this question, it is true enough.)